# stbi_load_from_memory not reading image dimensions correctly

Tags: c, image

I'm using `ld -r -b binary -o res.o *` in order to embed a folder full of several png images into my C program, among them one called `font.png`.

In my code, I am using this code to load the embedded `font.png` with stb_image:

```
char* img;
int w, h, n;
extern char* _binary_font_png_start;
extern char* _binary_font_png_end;
img = (char*)stbi_load_from_memory((unsigned char*)_binary_font_png_start, _binary_font_png_end - _binary_font_png_start, &w, &h, &n, 4);
```

The actual image dimensions are 256x128, but stbi gives me a value of 0 for w (width) and 2293200 for h (height). What went wrong?

Comment: Does your `end-start` calculated length match the length of the original PNG file? Did you check the return value?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Turns out that they're both the same. WTF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally managed to make it work by changing my code as follows:

```
char* img;
int w, h, n;
extern char _binary_font_png_start, _binary_font_png_end;
img = (char*)stbi_load_from_memory((unsigned char*)&_binary_font_png_start, &_binary_font_png_end - &_binary_font_png_start, &w, &h, &n, 4);
```

Kinda weird, but it works so I guess it's correct? Haven't been able to find any docs on the "intended" way of these symbols being linked into c code, but it seems they represent the char at the end/start of the binary data, rather than a pointer to that char as I'd expected.

Comment: Well done, and thank you for sharing back with the SO community. If the answer is correct, and works, you should accept it too - and get the points.

Comment: I also ran into the same issue and your solution helped me as well.  Thank you for sharing!